# Exception Exception RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a method `depart(plane)` which takes an error   `fail "The plane can't set off because it is stormy" if @weather.stormy?`. This is defined in my `airport class`

```
class Airport

  attr_accessor :planes, :landed, :weather

  def initialize(weather = Weather.new)
    #plane has no location when initialized

    @landed = nil
    @planes  = []
    @weather = weather

  end


  def land(plane)
    fail "You can't land this plane again!" if @landed == true
    @planes << plane
    @landed = true
  end

  def depart(plane)

    fail "The plane has already departed" if @landed == false
    fail "The plane can't set off because it is stormy" if @weather.stormy?
    @planes.pop
    puts "Your plane has left the airport!"
    @landed = false
    end
  end
```

I also have a plane class:

```
class Plane
end
```

The method `.stormy?` is a method in which a random number is generated. If the number is above 75, a storm is generated otherwise it is false. This is defined in my `weather class`

```
def stormy?
    number > 70 ? true : false
end

def number
    rand(1..100)
end
```

I am trying to test the error `fail "The plane can't set off because it is stormy" if @weather.stormy?`using RSpec. I am finding this extremely difficult as I am very new to RSpec.

The problem I am having is passing this test as the storm either can be true or false. How can I preset a value and test it?

My whole airport_spec.rb file:

```
require 'airport'
require 'plane'
require 'weather'

describe Airport do

  let(:airport) { Airport.new }
  let(:plane) { double :plane }
  let(:weather) { double :weather}
  #let(:weather) {double :weather}

  it 'creates new airports' do
    expect(:airport).to eq(:airport)
  end

  it 'accepts landed planes' do
    subject.land(:plane)
    expect(subject.landed).to be(true)
  end

 describe '#initialize' do
  it 'initializes a planes array when airport is instantiated' do
    expect(airport.planes).to be_an_instance_of(Array)
  end

  it 'initializes the plane to be landed to be nil upon instantiation' do
    expect(airport.landed).to be nil
  end

  it 'instantiates a new weather object upon initialization' do
    weather = airport.weather
    expect(airport.weather).to eq weather
  end
end

 describe '#land' do
   it 'adds a plane to the planes array when landed' do
    subject.land(:plane)
    expect(subject.planes).to eq [:plane]
  end

  it 'will not land a plane that is already landed' do

    subject.land(:plane)
    expect {subject.land(:plane)}.to raise_error("You can't land this plane again!")
  end
end

  describe '#depart' do

  it 'will not allow a plane to take off when it is stormy' do
   weather = Weather.new
   allow(weather).to receive(:stormy?).and_return true
   expect{subject.depart(plane)}.to raise_error("The plane can't set off because it is stormy")
   end
end

  describe '#full' do
    it 'will raise an error when the airport is too full' do
    expect(subject.full?).to eq(true)
    end
  end
end
```

The test that is failing:

```
    it 'will not allow a plane to take off when it is stormy' do
        weather = Weather.new
        allow(Airport.new).to receive(weather.stormy?).and_return true
        expect{subject.depart(plane)}.to raise_error("The plane can't set off because it is stormy")
    end
end
```

Why am I getting:

```
Failures:

  1) Airport#depart will not allow a plane to take off when it is stormy
     Failure/Error: expect{subject.depart(plane)}.to raise_error("The plane can't set off because it is stormy")
       expected Exception with "The plane can't set off because it is stormy" but nothing was raised
     # ./spec/airport_spec.rb:75:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.02878 seconds (files took 0.15908 seconds to load)
12 examples, 1 failure

RSpec version : 3.5.4
```

Another time I run:

```
Failures:

  1) Airport#depart will not allow a plane to take off when it is stormy
     Failure/Error: expect{subject.depart(plane)}.to raise_error("The plane can't set off because it is stormy")
       expected Exception with "The plane can't set off because it is stormy" but nothing was raised
     # ./spec/airport_spec.rb:58:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Airport#depart removes a plane from the planes array when taken-off
     Failure/Error: fail "The plane can't set off because it is stormy" if @weather.stormy?

     RuntimeError:
       The plane can't set off because it is stormy
     # ./lib/airport.rb:20:in `depart'
     # ./spec/airport_spec.rb:63:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.03361 seconds (files took 0.15734 seconds to load)
16 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/airport_spec.rb:56 # Airport#depart will not allow a plane to take off when it is stormy
rspec ./spec/airport_spec.rb:61 # Airport#depart removes a plane from the planes array when taken-off
```

However, sometimes it works and passes:

```
COVERAGE: 100.00% -- 76/76 lines in 6 files

Benjamins-MacBook-Pro:airport_challenge benjamin$ rspec

Airport
  creates new airports
  accepts landed planes
  #initialize
    initializes a planes array when airport is instantiated
    initializes the plane to be landed to be nil upon instantiation
    instantiates a new weather object upon initialization
  #land
    adds a plane to the planes array when landed
    will not land a plane that is already landed
  #depart
    will not allow a plane to take off when it is stormy
  #full
    will raise an error when the airport is too full

Plane
  creates new planes

Weather
  creates a weather object
  #number
    will create a random number
  #storm
    will either be stormy or sunny

Have you considered running rubocop? It will help you improve your code!
Try it now! Just run: rubocop

Finished in 0.01254 seconds (files took 0.15439 seconds to load)
13 examples, 0 failures


COVERAGE:  96.05% -- 73/76 lines in 6 files

+----------+----------------+-------+--------+---------+
| coverage | file           | lines | missed | missing |
+----------+----------------+-------+--------+---------+
|  83.33%  | lib/airport.rb | 18    | 3      | 25-27   |
+----------+----------------+-------+--------+---------+
5 file(s) with 100% coverage not shown
```

Comment: It's a little concerning that your `depart(plane)` method takes a plane as an argument, then calls `@planes.pop` without concern for what it's removing from the list. There isn't even a check to assert that `plane` is the last element. It's also very odd that those instance variables are not associated with tthe plane, or maybe they are but it's not clear from the method implementation. Is that an instance method on `Plane`?

Comment: I'll post my whole file so it can make more sense

Comment: The `.stormy?` method is on weather object. Why do you mock it on _airport_? (and a new instance of airport, not even the subject)

Comment: I changed it. I am getting NoMethodError: undefined method to_sym

Comment: But I am trying to create a testing environment by setting the storm to true and THEN expecting an error

Comment: I think you mean `@planes.delete(plane)` to remove it. `pop` always removes the last element if one is present. `@landed` also seems to be a property of the plane, airports don't "land", so it's a mystery as to why it's in the airport context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say `allow(Airport.new).to receive...` this is setting up a new `Airport`, *not* referring to the one you've set up using `let`.

The `stormy?` method is on `Weather` so the expectation should be:

```
allow(weather).to receive(:stormy?).and_return true
```

and set up the test subject to use the weather with the mocked `stormy?` method:

```
let(:weather) { double :weather }
subject { Airport.new(weather) }
```

---

As a side explanation, `receive` takes the **name** of a method that will be called. When you write `receive(weather.stormy?)` RSpec is trying to convert the *return value* from `weather.stormy?` (which would be `True` or `False`) into a symbol to use as the method name, hence `undefined method`to_sym'`.

---

Looking at the full version of your spec, you are currently an *implicit subject* i.e. based on the `describe Airport...` RSpec has created an `Airport` using `Airport.new` (with no arguments) to be the subject of your spec. This means that the subject isn't using the `weather` object where you've stubbed the `stormy?` method and so your real `stormy?` method is still being used. This is why I set up an *explicit subject* using `subject { Airport.new(weather) }`. Lastly, you don't want to be setting up a local `weather` in the test (`weather = Weather.new`) because you want `allow(weather)...` to refer to the weather from the `let` that's passed to the test subject.

---

Here's a complete version of the spec with the changes made:

```
require 'airport'

describe Airport do

  let(:weather) { double :weather }
  subject { Airport.new(weather) }
  let(:plane) { double :plane }

    it 'will not allow a plane to take off when it is stormy' do
      allow(weather).to receive(:stormy?).and_return true
      expect { subject.depart(plane) }.to raise_error("The plane can't set off because it is stormy")
    end

end
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The tests run green half of the time. Half of the other time I am still receiving the same error.

Comment: It is because the storm is still switching between true and false.

Comment: Which I want it to but the error isn't being raised when the storm is true

Comment: Can you add your current version of your spec at the end of the question? (keep the original code in case its helpful to anyone else in the future)

Comment: The error on line 75 in the spec/airport_spec.rb file is the relevant code I have provided

Comment: So it is the same test which is failing. It hasn't changed.

Comment: I have added the version number as requested.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, when I wrote *version*, I didn't mean version of RSpec, I meant your spec code as it currently stands **after** making the 2 fixes I suggested in my answer.

Comment: i.e. to see the code where "The tests run green half of the time. "

Comment: Ok, I will post my airport_spec.rb file. I know it looks like garbage but it is my first time writing TDD

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to help. This is my first time using TDD so please be patient :) Hopefully my edited post will help you understand what is going on.

Comment: I didn't post all my code to begin with because I was trying to make it an easy read.

Comment: I've updated the answer with an explanation based on the full spec that you posted.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was really comprehensive and I understand what I was doing wrong earlier. However, I am still receiving the same error.

Comment: Hi! I've just added the the complete source for an `airport_spec.rb` that contains just the working code for this example. You can try running that on its own and see if it passes for you, and maybe see if you can spot any differences between my code and yours. Cheers.