# Why am I getting a RunTimeError in my tests and the opposite boolean than expected?

Tags: ruby, rspec

What I don't understand is why not_stormy.stormy? is equating to true!!

As you can probably tell I'm almost completely new to both Ruby and Rspec. Any help is appreciated, even being pointed in the right direction with hints?

Here is my Rspec Test for Airport.rb

```
require 'airport'

describe Airport do

  class FakePlane
    attr_accessor :landed

    def initialize
      @landed = false
    end

    def landed?
      @landed
    end
  end

  class FakeWeather
    def stormy?
      false
    end
  end

  let(:plane) { FakePlane.new }
  let(:not_stormy) { FakeWeather.new }

  describe '#initialize' do
    it 'should hold zero amount of planes' do
      expect(subject.planes).to be_empty
    end
  end

  describe '#land_plane' do
    it "should instruct a plane to land" do
      p not_stormy.stormy?
      subject.land_plane(plane, not_stormy)
      expect(subject.planes[0]).to eq plane
    end
    it "should raise an error if plane has already landed" do
      subject.land_plane(plane, not_stormy)
      expect { subject.land_plane(plane, not_stormy) }.to raise_error "Sorry plane has already landed!" if subject.planes.include? plane
    end
  end

  describe '#take_off' do
    it "should instruct a plane to take off" do
      subject.land_plane(plane, weather)
      expect(subject.take_off(plane)).to eq plane
    end
    it 'should raise an error if there are no planes' do
      expect { subject.take_off(plane) }.to raise_error "Sorry, no planes!" if subject.planes.empty?
    end
  end

  describe '#take_off' do
    it "should instruct a plane to take off" do
      subject.land_plane(plane, weather)
      expect(subject.take_off(plane)).to eq plane
    end
    it 'should raise an error if there are no planes' do
      expect { subject.take_off(plane) }.to raise_error "Sorry, no planes!" if subject.planes.empty?
    end
  end

  class FakeWeather
    def stormy?
      true
    end
  end

  let(:weather) { FakeWeather.new }
  describe '#land_plane' do
    it 'should not land a plane if the weather is stormy' do
      expect { subject.land_plane(plane, weather) }.to raise_error "Sorry, too stormy to land!" if weather.stormy?
    end
  end
end
```

And here is the code from airport.rb

```
class Airport
  attr_reader :planes

  def initialize
    @planes = []
  end

  def land_plane(plane, weather, landed = true)
    @stormy = weather.stormy?
    fail "Sorry plane has already landed!" if @planes.include? plane
    fail "Sorry, too stormy to land!" if @stormy
    plane.landed = landed
    @planes << plane
  end

  def take_off(plane)
    fail "Sorry, no planes!" if @planes.empty?
    plane.landed = false
    @planes.delete(plane)
  end

end
```

And here, finally is my error message

```
Airport#take_off should instruct a plane to take off
     Failure/Error: fail "Sorry, too stormy to land!" if @stormy

     RuntimeError:
       Sorry, too stormy to land!
     # ./lib/airport.rb:14:in `land_plane'
     # ./spec/airport_spec.rb:56:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: Towards the end of your spec you're redefining `FakeWeather`'s `stormy?` method to return `true`. This is replacing the earlier `stormy?` that returns `false`

Comment: Also, a couple of weeks ago I was [helping somebody else](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46026166/) who was having trouble with the what sounds like the same exercise so I'm a bit curious where this coding exercise is from?

Comment: It's a challenge for a coding bootcamp and thanks for your help. I was able to solve it using: `allow(weather).to receive(:stormy?).and_return false` but I was wondering do I have to use that in every it...do...end statement? I was hoping to be able to set it and use condition to set the "not stormy" environment some how.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to create 2 weather objects and use the appropriate one in each test e.g.

```
let(:good_weather) do
  weather = double :weather
  allow(weather).to receive(:stormy?).and_return false
  weather
end

let(:bad_weather) do
  weather = double :weather
  allow(weather).to receive(:stormy?).and_return true
  weather
end
```

Or alternatively, break the tests up into "contexts". This probably makes more sense because when you think about it most of the tests are interested in testing other things and there's only one or two tests that are about checking planes can't land when it's stormy:

```
describe Airport do

  let(:plane) { FakePlane.new }
  let(:weather) do
    weather = double :weather
    allow(weather).to receive(:stormy?).and_return false
    weather
  end  

  describe '#initialize' do
    it 'should hold zero amount of planes' do
      expect(subject.planes).to be_empty
    end
  end

  describe '#land_plane' do
    it "should instruct a plane to land" do
      subject.land_plane(plane, weather)
      expect(subject.planes[0]).to eq plane
    end
    # ...
  end

  # ... more tests here

  context "when stormy" do
    let(:weather) do
      weather = double :weather
      allow(weather).to receive(:stormy?).and_return true
      weather
    end

    describe '#land_plane' do
      it 'should not land a plane' do
        expect { subject.land_plane(plane, weather) }.to raise_error "Sorry, too stormy to land!"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and then the RSpec output will format this nicely:

```
Airport
  #initialize
    should hold zero amount of planes
  #land_plane
    should instruct a plane to land
    should raise an error if plane has already landed
  #take_off
    should instruct a plane to take off
    should raise an error if there are no planes
  #take_off
    should instruct a plane to take off
    should raise an error if there are no planes
  when stormy
    #land_plane
      should not land a plane
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks, I like the context syntax. I've done that and it's all working!

Answer (score 0):

[mikej's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46511455/299774) is good but it does not explain why you had `stormy? == false` across all your specs. Let me explain:

This is your specs stripped down to relevant parts and simplified:

```
  class FakeWeather
    def stormy?
      false
    end
  end

  it { expect(FakeWeather.new.stormy?).to eq(false) } # fail

  class FakeWeather
    def stormy?
      true
    end
  end

  it { expect(FakeWeather.new.stormy?).to eq(true) } # success
```

You probably though that what is happening is:

1. you define not stormy FakeWeather class
2. spec `expect(FakeWeather.new.stormy?).to eq(false)` is run
3. you redefine stormy FakeWeather class
4. spec `it { expect(FakeWeather.new.stormy?).to eq(true) }` is run

But this is **not what is happening**, here's what's really happening:

1. you define not stormy FakeWeather
2. you add an example to be run (it's not run yet, this is what `it/specify` does - you pass a block to it to be run later)
3. you redefine stormy FakeWeather
4. you add another example to be run
5. examples are run, but in memory there's a stormy class defined.

Comment: Ah, I see, yes that makes sense and you're assumption was right!